# Cannot figure out how to use getSource from another class

Tags: java, swing

I have decided it was about time for me to learn how to make GUIs in java. Everything was coming along nicely until I began to set up my ActionListener.

Heres my actionListener class:

```
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Calculator implements ActionListener
{
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
  {
    if (e.getSource() == set)
    {
      setAllTheThings();
    }
  }
  private void setAllTheThings()
  {
    System.out.println("hello");
  }
}
```

What I cannot seem to do is get the actionListener to find the JButton called "set" in another class. How should I go about doing this?

Also, here's said button:

```
JButton set = new JButton("Set");
set.setLocation(255,0);
set.setSize(50,20);
set.addActionListener(new Calculator());
line1.add(set);
```

Comment: Let me clarify: I intend to use this class to recieve actions from 3 buttons and 4 different combo boxes, and I just want to find out what object sent the action. For example, if the JButton "set" was pressed, I want to be able to figure out that it was pressed and act accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement the same code using `Actions` - checking the source is not a good way to see the origin of the event.

See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html

Comment: Ok, this looks like what I need, I'll get back to you on whether or not I actually get it to work.

Comment: That's the standard and best way in Swing - also allow you to have multiple sources for an event - typically menu and button (or toolbar) and an hotkey as in "save"

Comment: Well, it works perfectly! Thanks for saving my AP Comp Sci project!